# "Reverse" JSON Status API

Tags: json, api

I've been wondering how to fetch the PlayStation server status. They display it on this page:

https://status.playstation.com/en-us/

But PlayStation is known to use APIs instead of PHP database fetches. After looking around in the source code of the site, I found that they have a separate file called /data.json.

https://status.playstation.com/en-us/data.json

The content of this file is the same as the index file (for some reason). They use stuff like {{endDateTitle}} and {{message}}, but I can't find where it's defined, if it's pulled using a separate file or just pulled from a database using PHP.

How can I "reverse" this site and see if there's a API I can use to display the status on my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I did not get the question right, but it seems pretty straightforward.

If using firefox, open Developer tools, Network. Reload the page.
You can clearly see the requested URL

```
https://status.playstation.com/data/statuses/region/SCEA.json
```

It seems that an empty list as a status means "No problems" (since there are no problems I cannot verify this assumption. That's all

The parenthesis `{{}}` are used by various HTML templating languages, like [angular](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax), so you'd have to go through the js code to understand where they get updated.

Comment: You did get the question right! I was using Chrome and have looked through the recorded URLs but couldn't find a link. This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot Nico!